# What is a good substitute for Barramundi fish?

Tags: substitutions, fish

I am cooking a recipe that uses Barramundi fish:

https://www.blueapron.com/recipes/honey-butter-barramundi-with-za-atar-roasted-vegetables

**Unfortunately I have never seen this species of fish in a grocery store and so I need some help. What is a good substitute for Barramundi fish?**

Answer (score 5):

[Barramundi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barramundi) is an Asian fish also commonly eaten in Australia deep fried in dishes like fish and chips. It is very similar not only in shape but also in consistency and taste to perch.

Any type of [perch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perch) like Egyptian [Nile Perch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nile_perch) which can be easily found in most markets (depending on your location) is a good substitute.

[Grouper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grouper) can also make a good substitute although it has slightly higher fat content and may be a bit more expensive fish.

Most [Sea Bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_bass) being the same family and providing similar firmness can probably constitute a good alternative too.

Answer (score 3):

Barramundi is an Asian sea bass.  Any firm-fleshed, white fish will be a fine substitute.

Answer (score 1):

Grouper would come close.  Your sea bass next.  I am a little to far east for this fish but a very few stays. I would use Grouper.